# Jquery UI - Range Slider - only move slider when clicking on slider handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using Jquery UI to create a slider. Here the link: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range. I need the slider to only move when clicking on the slider handle (the grey squares). Right now it moves if you click on or outside or those grey squares. Thanks!

Comment: Surely clicking the handles of a range slider wouldn't AND shouldn't do anything. How would it know if you wanted to increase or decrease the value when you click on a control that could be moved in either direction?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The handle bar moves both when you click and drag it and when you click outside of it. I want it to only move when you click and drag the handle bar (the grey square). I honestly don't understand why you gave me negative rating for that question. If you click on the link I posted it's easy to understand what I'm saying.

Comment: The word 'drag' is key here. Your question asks for a solution to move the slider on click with no mention of drag. It's apparent now that what you actually wanted was to *prevent* clicks that are not on the handles from affecting the range. Hence the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

I actually just fixed this using CSS. If anyone else has this issue, my solution was basically to remove the pointer event from the outside div id and keep it only on the ui-slider-handle. Hope this helps someone else :)

```css
#slider-range { pointer-events: none; }
#slider-range .ui-slider-handle { pointer-events: auto; }
```

If you want to change this for all sliders you can use this Global CSS:

```css
.ui-slider { pointer-events: none; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle { pointer-events: auto; }
```

Comment: I made mine generic to handle all sliders.

```css
.ui-slider { pointer-events: none; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle { pointer-events: auto; }
```